# How to DownLoad Mail Attachment by using EWS in Exchange

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I am using ASP.Net MVC.

```
using (ExchangeServiceBinding exchangeServer = new ExchangeServiceBinding())
{
    ICredentials creds = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    exchangeServer.Credentials = creds;
    exchangeServer.Url = "https://myexchangeserver.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";

    FindItemType findItemRequest = new FindItemType();
    findItemRequest.Traversal = ItemQueryTraversalType.Shallow;

    // define which item properties are returned in the response
    ItemResponseShapeType itemProperties = new ItemResponseShapeType();
    itemProperties.BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.AllProperties;
    findItemRequest.ItemShape = itemProperties;

    // identify which folder to search
    DistinguishedFolderIdType[] folderIDArray = new DistinguishedFolderIdType[1];
    folderIDArray[0] = new DistinguishedFolderIdType();
    folderIDArray[0].Id = DistinguishedFolderIdNameType.inbox;

    // add folders to request
    findItemRequest.ParentFolderIds = folderIDArray;

    // find the messages
    FindItemResponseType findItemResponse = exchangeServer.FindItem(findItemRequest);

    // read returned
    FindItemResponseMessageType folder = (FindItemResponseMessageType)findItemResponse.ResponseMessages.Items[0];
    ArrayOfRealItemsType folderContents = new ArrayOfRealItemsType();
    folderContents = (ArrayOfRealItemsType)folder.RootFolder.Item;
    ItemType[] items = folderContents.Items;

    // if no messages were found, then return null -- we're done
    if (items == null || items.Count() <= 0)
    { return null; }


    // FindItem never gets "all" the properties, so now that we've found them all, we need to get them all.
    BaseItemIdType[] itemIds = new BaseItemIdType[items.Count()];
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count(); i++)
    {
        itemIds[i] = items[i].ItemId;
    }


    GetItemType getItemType = new GetItemType();
    getItemType.ItemIds = itemIds;
    getItemType.ItemShape = new ItemResponseShapeType();
    getItemType.ItemShape.BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.AllProperties;
    getItemType.ItemShape.BodyType = BodyTypeResponseType.HTML;
    getItemType.ItemShape.BodyTypeSpecified = true;

    GetItemResponseType getItemResponse = exchangeServer.GetItem(getItemType);
    ItemType[] messages = new ItemType[getItemResponse.ResponseMessages.Items.Count()];
    List<MailRecipientModel> model = new List<MailRecipientModel>();
    for (int j = 0; j < messages.Count(); j++)
    {
        messages[j] = ((ItemInfoResponseMessageType)getItemResponse.ResponseMessages.Items[j]).Items.Items[0];
        MailRecipientModel model1 = new MailRecipientModel();

        model1.Subject = messages[j].Subject;
        model1.FromAddress = messages[j].Sender.Item.EmailAddress;
        model1.DisplayName = messages[j].Sender.Item.Name;
        model1.Date = messages[j].DateTimeReceived.Date.ToString();
        model1.MailBody = messages[j].Body.Value;
        model1.MsgId = messages[j].ItemId.Id;
        if (messages[j].Attachments != null) {
            //
        }
        model.Add(model1);
    }              

    return model;
}
```

This my code  I wanna download attachment file and if attachment file is image so its display in browser.

I am using Microsoft ActiveSync Exchange Server.

If you know how to do so please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public List<FileAttachment> getAttachmentFromExchangeAccount( ExchangeAccounts exchangeAccount, String attachmentId, String itemId) {
    ExchangeService service = obtainExchangeService(exchangeAccount);
    List<FileAttachment> fileAttachmentsEWS = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(service, new ItemId(attachmentId), new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Attachments));
        message.load();
        for (Attachment attachment : message.getAttachments()) {
            attachment.load();
            if (attachment.getId().equals(itemId)) {
                FileAttachment fileAttachment = (FileAttachment) attachment;
                fileAttachment.load();
                fileAttachmentsEWS.add(fileAttachment);
            }
        }
    } catch (ServiceLocalException e) {
        LOG.debug("OUT NOK loadAttachmentFile ServiceLocalException");
        LOG.debug(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.debug("OUT NOK loadAttachmentFile Exception");
        LOG.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
    return fileAttachmentsEWS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the GetAttachment operation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa494316(v=exchg.150).aspx . There is a Proxy code sample https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vikas/2007/10/15/howto-ews-use-getattachment-to-download-attachments-off-mailappointment/

Comment: I don't want to download attachment files in my server. i just wanna give a direct mail sever download link. is it possible?

Comment: Not directly but just create an endpoint you can send the AttachmentId to and then process the AttachmentId on the Server using EWS and send back the content to browser. At the end of the day your code is going to need to be authenticated to access any attachment. The API call to access any Attachment using EWS is the GetAttachment Operation for which you need the AttachmentId.

Comment: do you have any example?

Comment: There is a example of using GetAttachment in EWS in the link i posted. Creating something to submit the AttachmentId in ASP.Net MVC should be pretty simple 101 stuff. You should try to do it yourself and then ask a question around what you don't understand.

Comment: You can't do that using EWS, MSG is an Outlook File or to be more correct its a compound OLE format. There is no easy way outside of Outlook to do work with those files https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn672317(v=exchg.150).aspx. You can save a message as an EML format using EWS and the MimeStream but this is not the same as MSG and doesn't not maintain the fidelity of an Item that same as MSG but for most uses its fine.